# How to update a field which have a blank space in it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a field called "shop rate" in my Database. I want to update this field in PHP MySql.
I am using Codeigniter update_string() function to update the field values.

I have tried in two way but did not get any result..

1st is the simple way that we use regularly..
$posted["shop rate"] = $this->input->post('shop_rate');

after this i get my Sql query like this
UPDATE `table_name` SET `shop` rate = '545454' WHERE i_id = '190';

2nd is, I have used backtick that is (``) (`shop rate`). but still it did not work.

$posted[`shop rate`] = $this->input->post('shop_rate');
and my sql query is
UPDATE `table_name` SET `shop` rate` = '545454' WHERE i_id = '190';

Thanks in advance

Comment: show the code with actual query "declaration"

Comment: `$posted[`shop rate`]` doesn't exist, it's double quote `" "` or single `' '`. Plus, you really should use variable that does not contain blank space

Comment: please show place where you "inject" $posted["shop rate"] to your query

Comment: Variables or array indexes which use blank spaces should be avoided.

Comment: actually that shows blank because  i have used back tricks in it that is (``) `shop rate`. i used a blank space field because my DB is linked to access database.

Comment: I read the field value like 

$posted["shop rate"]        = trim($this->input->post('shop_rate'),true);

and i update it 

$i_aff = $this->acs_model->edit_data($this->db->DEALER,$posted, array('i_id'=>decrypt($h_id)));

and the edit_data function goes here

function edit_function
{
$s_qry = $this->db->update_string($table, $info, $where);
            echo $s_qry; exit;    
   $st = $this->db->simple_query($s_qry);
            if(!$affected_rows)
    return $st;
   else
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

Comment: @sarojkumarchoudhury unfortunately CI Active Record doesn't support table names with spaces.

Comment: 'shop rate' is not a table name @Viral its Field Name

Comment: Also it doesn't support field names with spaces. You need to write custom query for it using `$this->db->query();` @sarojkumarchoudhury

Answer (score 1):

Your update query seems to have problem. Check shop` rate. Change it

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `shop rate` = '545454' WHERE i_id = '190';
```

Comment: Thanks @Harshit for your answer. I know this will work.
If I apply this then I have to write whole query manually.

I want something by which the query will convert 
$posted["shop rate "] to SET `shop rate` = '545454'.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table_name SET `shop rate` = '545454' WHERE i_id = '190';
```

will work

EDIT: also, sorry for not noticing earlier:
    $posted[`shop rate`]
    should be $posted['shop rate']

EDIT2: part of answer was wrong, omitted that

Comment: Thanks for your concern #Brano, your first answer will work but second one will not work. 
And what I really want i have mentioned it above @harshit's Comment. Please review it.

Comment: How are you building the query? did you try something like `shop%20rate or  (backbracket backtric)shop rate(backbracket backtric) ? (sorry, first time comenting on this site, not really sure how to format the text here properly..